# How to assign tag values for tableviews in one view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have to call two tableviews in one view controller .I have assigned tag value for first tableview ,I'm getting the data for only one tableview,other is not showing any data .How can I get the data for both tableviews.

I have assigned `firsttableview.tag=1`

```
    (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if(tableView.tag==1){
                  FirstTableViewCell *cell1=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ProfileTableViewCell"];

        if(!cell1){
            cell1=[[FirstTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"FirstTableViewCell"];
        }
        cell1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        cell1.dateLbl.text=@"ios";
        cell1.timeLbl.text=@"9:30AM";
        //[self.secondTableView reloadData];
        return cell1;

    }
           SecondTableViewCell *cell1=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SecondTableViewCell"];

        if(!cell1){
            cell1=[[SecondTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"SecondTableViewCell"];
        }
        cell1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        cell1.locationLbl.text=@"Hyderabad";
           return cell1;
   } 
   }
```

Comment: Where is else in your code ? please post proper code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and also post numberOfRows method code.

Answer (score 1):

Check tableview using their objects like `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if ([tableView isEqual: table1]) {

```
UITableViewCell *cell1 = [[UITbaleViewCell alloc] init];

return cell1
```

}

else if ([tableView isEqual: table2]){

```
 UITableViewCell *cell2 = [[UITbaleViewCell alloc] init];

return cell2

}
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use `tag` property. Instead there is much better way.

1. You connect two `UITableView`s with your controller.

   ```
   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewA;
   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewB;
   ```
2. Then in your `viewDidLoad()`

   ```
   self.tableViewA.dataSource = self;
   self.tableViewB.dataSource = self;
   ```
3. Handle your `DataSource` methods accordingly

   ```
   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
       if (tableView == self.tableViewA) {
           return 1;  //return according to your need
       } else if (tableView == self.tableViewB) {
           return 1;  //return according to your need
       }
       return 0;
   }

   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
       if (tableView == self.tableViewA) {
           return 5;  //return according to your need
       }else if (tableView == self.tableViewB) {
           return 8;  //return according to your need
       }
       return 0;  
   }


   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init];
       if (tableView == self.tableViewA) {
           cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellA" forIndexPath:indexPath];
           cell.textLabel.text = @"Type A";
       } else if (tableView == self.tableViewB) {
           cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellB" forIndexPath:indexPath];
           cell.textLabel.text = @"Type B";
       }
       return cell;
   }
   ```